# Website down after disabling tls 1.0/1.1 and ssl2.0/3.0

Tags: ssl, iis, registry, tls1.2, group-policy

Been busy securing my servers with disabling SSL2.0/SSL3.0/TLS1.0/TLS1.1.
I have for about 50 servers, all Windows Server 2012 and newer. First I used a powershell script to add the registry-keys for disabling SSL2.0/3.0/TLS1.0/1.1. This because I could easily rollback those settings when any server would give some troubles. (Yes, rebooted all).

After a couple of weeks I decided to apply a group policy (So new added servers to the domain would directly have secure settings). The only thing I configured in the groupPolicy was to add the registry keys (which all servers already had).

So, now the groupPolicy is active but a few servers with IIS installed are giving me some problems. When I browse to the hosted website on the IIS server my browser (In this example InternetExplorer) is giving the error "Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting.".
(Other browsers just say they can't connect)

[image]

I'm sure the problem doesn't relay on the client side.. (Nothing has changed to IE settings)
I just can't seem to figure it out.. It's the same settings as the first test with the powershell script.. So actually, nothing should have changed to the registry with the groupPolicy..
I even tried the enable all the protocols again (SSL2.0/3.0/TLS1.0/1.1) But the error stays the same..

Keys applied first with powershell and later with a groupPolicy:

```
$RegKey = “HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols”
New-Item               “$RegKey\TLS 1.2\Server” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.2\Server” -name 'Enabled' -value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.2\Server” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-Item               “$Regkey\TLS 1.2\Client” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.2\Client” -name 'Enabled' -value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.2\Client” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-Item               “$Regkey\SSL 2.0\Server” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\SSL 2.0\Server” -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\SSL 2.0\Server” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-Item               “$Regkey\SSL 2.0\Client” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\SSL 2.0\Client” -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\SSL 2.0\Client” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-Item               “$Regkey\SSL 3.0\Server” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\SSL 3.0\Server” -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\SSL 3.0\Server” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-Item               “$Regkey\SSL 3.0\Client” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\SSL 3.0\Client” -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\SSL 3.0\Client” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-Item               “$Regkey\TLS 1.0\Server” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.0\Server” -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.0\Server” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-Item               “$Regkey\TLS 1.0\Client” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.0\Client” -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.0\Client” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-Item               “$Regkey\TLS 1.1\Server” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.1\Server” -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.1\Server” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-Item               “$Regkey\TLS 1.1\Client” -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.1\Client” -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path “$Regkey\TLS 1.1\Client” -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
```

PS. Yes, I rebooted every single time I made changes to the registry..

Any thought?

Comment: Take a look at:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#configuring-schannel-protocols-in-the-windows-registry